# Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise, polyfills

I have been getting this specific error("Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]") in Internet Explorer which seems to be pertaining to polyfills. This seems to be happening when a new promise is created while loading few javascript files. I don't see this issue in other browsers which makes me think it could be a polyfills issue.

Following are the contents in my polyfills.js file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

following is the code where the Promise is created:

```
export const loadFile = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    loadScript('scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js').then(
      () => {
        loadScript((window as any).someUrl).then(
          () => { resolve(); },
          () => { reject(); },
        );
      },
      () => {
        reject();
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Not sure what I am missing. This is the error I see in the developer tools

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
   at Z (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:13528)
   at Z (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:13092)
   at Anonymous function 
   (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:14322)
   at e.prototype.invokeTask 
  (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:8178)
   at onInvokeTask (httpurl/main.0460452a7b0bcdb247fe.js:1:62633)
   at e.prototype.invokeTask 
  (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:8178)
   at t.prototype.runTask 
(url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:3458)
   at g (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:10562)
   at t.invokeTask (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:9414)
   at m (url/polyfills.4ac2578f6ae1e7f25aa5.js:1:22829)"
```

Comment: Since the [promise is not supported in IE browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), whether you have installed the related polyfills for it. Please try to use the following polyfills: [Promise Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) and [angular-promise-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-promise-polyfill). Besides, you could also check the polyfills.ts file, make sure the related import for the IE browser is uncommented.

Comment: That really helped! thanks a bunch!